# Is there a way to rate-limit an rsync user?

Tags: rsync, limit

I have a user with a Shell account(with jailkit) that insists on rsyncing 500gb of data on a daily basis.

Is there a way to limit that rsync to say just 2mbits per sec? If I have to do it by IP, how would I know the IP the user is rsyncing to, and what would I use to do it? IP-TABLES??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like user wouldn't voluntarily play nice and use --bwlimit each time they invoke `rsync`.

`--bwlimit=RATE          limit socket I/O bandwidth`

`iptables` approach may be covered by this question+answer:

[serverfault.com: how can I limit per user bandwidth?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth)

Comment: THanks for the example for IP-table but that will only set a total transfer limit of 100gb for example. I need to find a way to confine him to like 2mb per sec, he can take or download all he wants at that rate. Yeah, he wouldn't voluntarily play nice.

Comment: I think a better example would be this: http://serverfault.com/a/191605/253872
However in reverse, the IP I'm trying to rate-limit isn't on my side of the network.. I may have to alter the script from INPUT to OUTPUT on the IPTABLES to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jailkit so I am not sure about the exact details to implement this, but you could use sluice (http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/sluice/) to rate limit the traffic.

A simple solution could be to replace the rsync binary in the user chroot environment with a trivial shell script like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
rsync "$@" | sluice ...
```